# Why do we use a weighted average of child entropies when we calculate information gain?

Tags: decision-trees

In the decision tree algorithm, why do we use a weighted average of child entropies when we calculate information gain? What is wrong about using the arithmetic mean of entropies?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! There are different decision tree algorithms. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @nbro Thank you! Well, in more general sense rather than particular one. It's part of an exercise to be honest...